# How to show exact URL with escaped characters in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, character-encoding

I have a url like this : http://www.refskou.dk/safari-%F8.html
The file is named like this: safari-ø.html

The file consists of this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
alert(this.location);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But it does not print out /safari-%F8.html nor safari-ø.html

It prints out the question mark indicating that it does not know of the character "ø".
All I want is to print out the URL as I see it in the address bar.

Please give me a hint. This is only a problem in Safari as far as I have testet.
I need to tell you that I do not have control over what kind of charset used on the page. I can only execute javascript :-)

---

In response to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050885/how-to-show-exact-url-with-escaped-characters-in-safari/6051251#6051251).

The reason for the lack of control, is that I do a script that can be included to hopefully any webpage, and so I have no control over what kind of charset used. The included script can ofcouse have its own charset, introduced by the charset attribute on the "script" tag but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally got it working. For some reason Safari cannot understand the strange characters when asking from this/window.location. But moving down a level to the document object and asking for the URL gives me just what I need. Why this is, I cannot tell  you, but it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
unescape('/safari-%F8.html') == 'safari-ø.html'
```

Note that Safari still gives you a `?`, but Chrome shows either a `%F8` or `ø`

In Safari (nevermind):

```
var str = '/safari-%F8.html';
alert(str.replace(/%[A-F0-9]{2}/g, function(v){ return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v.substr(1), 16)); }));
```

The above works on normal strings, but Safari is seeing that character as unicode 65533, and I'm not sure how to convert that back to ASCII 248...

Comment: Exactly. I need to get rid of the ? in Safari and get it to show me %F8

Answer (score 0):

Try the [unescape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) javascript function:
`alert(unescape(this.location));`

Comment: Does not work, it still shows me the ?. I think that it is some specific Safari behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to specify a character set.

The first thing in your Head section...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

[More Info Here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

---

**EDIT:**  I missed the part where the OP states he has no control over the character set on the page.  I believe this is the root of the problem and wonder why he has no control over this.